# Asana Connect (OAuth) does not work on .ME domain name ?

Tags: php, asana

I am working on an experimental Asana agile dashboard app in PHP. This issue is strange, "Sign in with Asana"  is working fine in all the TLD's  (tested  .com, .info, .in and .net) except .ME TLD, this was spotted, when I was deploying app from development environment accessed at **abc.com** to **abc.me**.

At .ME TLD environment,  Asana Connect throws following 400 error  "
invalid_request: The `redirect_uri` parameter does not match a valid url for the application."

But same codebase in .COM TLD, works just fine.

Is there any work around to fix this issue?

Any help much appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The URI needs to match that specified in the app. So if you register the app in Asana as "abc.com", and then you try to redirect to "abc.me", it won't match. This is by design of the OAuth standard.

Comment: @ Agnoster: I did verified this, for abc.me instance, I created a new app in asana with abc.me url and it did'n work, however it worked fine with other TLD's (also updating the Asana app url to relevant TLD). Problem is with .me domain and that is weird.

Comment: It doesn't look like there should be any reason .me would be singled out. Can you contact support and include the domain names in question? We may need to investigate the actual apps and see what's up.